# Google apps script "exception: cannot retrieve the next object" when trying to run user-defined function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I put together an add-on to automate some processes in Google Sheets and published it internally to my domain. Users occasionally get the below error when trying to run the add-on; when I try to rerun on the same files, I get the same error.

> exception: cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end

Looking at the logs, the line that triggers the error is the one marked below:

```
function setupFilePrepVars() {
  // some setup stuff for subsequent work/function calls. built with the idea that this is the first function executed in a given step
  let filePrepSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  checkSheetNames(filePrepSS, fptExpectedNames);  <<<< offending line
  ...
```

`fptExpectedNames` is an array of strings. Also, as noted in the comment, `setupFilePrepVars` is called in the first line of the script.

The logs don't actually specify a line within this function, so I think the problem is with one of the inputs, but in case it's relevant, here's the definition:

```
function checkSheetNames(ss, expectedNames) {
  let sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let names = [];
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    names.push(sheet.getName());
  };
  // add check of expectedNames
  for (let expected of expectedNames) {
    if (names.indexOf(expected) === -1) {
      throw `Missing sheet "${expected}" in "${ss.getName()}" spreadsheet`;
    };
  };
};
```

I've searched around and haven't been able to identify the root cause, but I've been able to hackily resolve the error when it comes up by making a copy of the spreadsheet and rerunning the script there.

Comment: Why not just filter sheet names so that only sheets with expected names are used ie something like `ss.getSheet().filter(sh => ~expectedNames.indexOf(sh.getName()))` or even includes().

Comment: that might work, but that doesn't seem to address the error directly, since no lines in `checkSheetNames` are specified in the logged error.

Comment: I think.. (don't know for sure) that the array `sheets` contains 10 sheets so the `for-of` loop will itterate 10 times. But if the user does not have acces to 1 sheet then there is not a next object? @Cooper could that be it?